# getting connection error refused when trying to send email with Angular 7 and php

Tags: php, angular

I am trying to wire up a contact form built in Angular 7 with a php back end to send the form.  When I console the form data in my contact.component.ts file, it shows fine.  Here is what I am using to try to send this to my Php file:

```
onSubmit(form) { 
    this.apiService.sendEmail(form)
    .subscribe((Contact: Contact[])=>{
      this.contact = Contact;
   });
}
}
```

My api.service.ts is:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Contact } from './contact';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {
  PHP_API_SERVER = "http://127.0.0.1:8080";
  contact: Contact[]

  sendEmail(form): Observable<Contact[]>{
    return this.httpClient.post<Contact[]>(`${this.PHP_API_SERVER}/contact/contactMail.php`, this.contact);
  }
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
}
```

and finally my contactMail.php file, which is in the contact folder in src/app  is:

```
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
 header("Access-Control-Request-Headers: GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT");
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept,Accept-Language,Content-Language,Content-Type');
// Get the posted data.
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");

if(isset($postdata) && !empty($postdata))
{
  // Extract the data.
  $request = json_decode($postdata);
}
$name = htmlspecialchars($request->name);

$email=htmlspecialchars($request->email);
$phone=htmlspecialchars($request->phone);
$project=htmlspecialchars($request->project);
$notes=htmlspecialchars($request->notes);
$emailTo = "jg@gmail.com";

$to = $emailTo;
$subject = "Correspondence from the Website";
$headers = "From: " .$name. "\r\n";
$body = "Name: ".$name."\n Email: ".$email."\n
Would like info on: " .$project." \nComments: " .$notes." \n";
$body = wordwrap($body,70);
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

$result = array('message'=>"Thank You " .$name." Your request has been sent.");

echo json_encode($result);
```

when I run this locally I get an error that states: `POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/contact/contactMail.php net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`
I have tried to figure this out on my own and have read through several tutorials, but I am still stumped.  Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can't send email in PHP with localhost

Comment: @Mahmoudi, I do know that, I am just trying to get it to read my file.  Once I have that accomplished I can move it to my production server to verify the email gets sent.